# App points to production url when build with release mode at staging/test environment

Tags: c#, .net, release, visual-studio-debugging, staging

Hi i have a windows desktop app that has a weird issue.
When i build the solution in debug mode(with staging url) it works perfectly fine but when i switch to release mode it somehow takes me to production url (not the staging one).
I have seperate config files for staging and production with respective urls defined in them. Please suggest some possible solutions to this. Thanks!

Comment: Which kind of desktop app did you really create? Maybe a screen shot would be better for us to really understand this issue? If the url has been changed in release mode, could you just use the Find and Replace tool in your VS? I mean that maybe you could find the URLusing this tool directly, and then find the real reason. Or you could debug your app using Step Into, and find the differences in two modes. No sample is hard for me to repro this issue, if still no help, if possible, provide a simple sample using one drive would be better.

Comment: Would you please share the latest information about this issue in your side?